# Is it possible to assign code review to random reviewer(s) in JetBrains Upsource?

Tags: upsource

That would be useful so that good coding practices get spread more efficiently amongst the users.

If the users can just pick who will review then they might end up choosing people who agree with their ways of doing things: good or bad. So allowing for random reviewer would help. Even better if the algorithm would not be random but would just find a way to cover reviewers who have not reviewed the users code before.

I noticed the `Custom workflows` under `Edit project` but I do not see any option to assign randomly or programatically, unless a regex can return randomly.

Comment: i kind of feel this question is off the topic for stackoverflow. Possibly there is some other stackexchange platform. You seem to have higher points and are a better to judge my feeling.

Comment: @Vasif I think it is appropriate according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic eg. : software tools commonly used by programmers (check) and a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development (check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Custom workflows, there's a trigger to "Assign review participants automatically". There, if you add a bunch of people, then you can assign either all, or N random out of the whole bunch. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome. I wish it was an easier way to tell that this is possible though, like a hints box near the settings with suggestions of what can be done (I know this might be in the documentation, but I do not think I found it).